Given 2 Kripke structures M1 and M2, if there exists a simulation from M1 to M2 and a simulation from M2 to M1, is there a bisimulation from M1 to M2?
Given two kripke structures $M_1$ and $M_2$, if $M_1\leq_{sim}M_2$ and $M_2\leq_{sim}M_1$, then does $M_1\leq_{b-sim}M_2$ holds?
intuitively, I think that it's not true, since two simulations are achieved with two different relations; while a bisimulation is "stronger", in a sense that it's one relation that acts as two simulations. But I couldn't find a counter example to aforementioned claim.

Yes your intuition is correct. The fact is that the 2 relations can be disjoint when considering just one-sided simulation relations but for bisimulation we need 1 relation with symmetry which is stronger.
One counterexample is:

$M_1\leq_{sim}M_2$ with relation {(s0, t0),(s1, t2),(s2, t2) }
$M_2\leq_{sim}M_1$ with relation {(t0, s0),(t1, s1),(t2, s1), (t3, s2) }
However for a bisimulation relation we need the tuple (s1,t1) as no other state except s1 in M1 is such that $t_1\leq_{sim}s_i$. But then s_1 has a transition to itself where L(s1) = "red" but t_1 cannot match that behaviour in M_2. So M_1 and M_2 are not bisimulation equivalent.
They are however "simulation equivalent", where we define an equivalence relation between 2 LTS as ≃ = ≼ ∩ ≼-1
